# Pointer confusion causing "no matching function call for std::vector"?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have a C++ class that has a datamember:

```
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> *edges;
```

Then in my constructor, I do the following:

```
//rows and columns are dynamically set in constructor
edges = new vector<vector<int> >(rows*columns, vector<int>());
edges[0].push_back(1);
```

When running my program, I get

```
error: no matching function for call to std::vector<std::vector<int> >::push_back(int)
          edges[0].push_back(1); 
                              ^
```

I just know this has to do with pointers/references but I'm not experienced enough with C++ to figure it out and this error message feels so vague. Anybody know whats wrong here with these two lines?

EDIT1: I also tried changing the datamember to an object (not a pointer) and doing this but now my program is just stalling

```
for (int i = 0; i < (rows*columns); i++) {
    vector<int> neighbors;
    edges.push_back(neighbors);
}
```

EDIT2: I also tried using paxdiablo's answer but now this line is throwing a bad_alloc

```
edges = new vector<vector<int> >(rows*columns, vector<int>());
```

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to a vector rather than without the pointer?  An empty vector takes up very little space.

Comment: If you are inexperienced, you should drop a heavy coffee mug on your foot every time you consider using a pointer.  Only use pointers when no other method exists.  Prefer to use references.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to C++ so I thought if u have a dynamic size I would have to create a pointer and then assign it to a new object later on

Comment: The problem is if I use just `std::vector<std::vector<int>> edges;` for my datamember instead of a pointer, i get an error `no match for operator=` since you can't set like that

Comment: A vector uses dynamic memory to contain its data.  No need for you to create pointers to vectors.  By the way, you should drop another mug on the other foot whenever you consider dynamically allocating memory.  In few circumstances, do *you* need to use dynamic memory.  Many programs can be written without you using dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Remember that you are using a vector of columns.  The outer vector is a vector of rows.  In order to push to the outer vector, it must be a vector of columns.  So, build a vector of columns (temporary local variable), then push the vector (of columns) to your outer vector.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example you can provide, since it's hard for me to understand how I can create a vector of vectors without atleast using pointers at some point. If I just loop over the object and create new vectors inside, i'd still need to use pointers?

Comment: This is an adjacency list, so the columns have to be empty vectors

Comment: @Thomas, I'm hoping you mean raw pointers, smart pointers are brilliant. The problem with references is that they must refer to a real thing (no nullptr). There are use cases where pointers are better, unless you want monstrosities like optional references :-)

Comment: Ok, let me clarify.  Pointers in general should be avoided.  If you must use a pointer, then use a smart pointer.  Some topics, like polymorphism, need pointers.  Linked lists need pointers.   In Embedded Systems, pointers are often used to access Hardware Components (so smart pointers kind of screw things up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of loading a 2d vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board;
for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
{
   std::vector<int> row;
   for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column)
   {
       row.push_back((row * 4) + column);
   }
   board.push_back(row);
}
```

The above code initializes a 2d array, 4x4, with a unique number for each slot/square.

The inner loop initializes a "row" vector.
After the "row" vector is initialized, it is "push_back" to the "board" vector.

Comment: Wow!  No pointers!

Comment: Thank u, I see what u mean now!

Answer (score 0):

`edges` is a pointer so `edges[0]` is actually the *outer* vector and you can't  append an integer to a vector of vectors.

What you need is something like:

```
(*edges)[0].push_back(1);
```

The dereference gives you the outer vector, then the `[0]` gives you the first inner vector, which you *can* append an integer to.

There are other ways to do this,  but the intent here is to simply explain what is happening.

---

Specifically, it's probably better to declare the *vector* in your class rather than a pointer to the vector. That way, you get it automagically during construction and you need not worry about allocating (or deallocating) it manually.

To do that, you simply use something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

struct IntMatrix
{
    IntMatrix(unsigned cols = 1U, unsigned rows = 1U)
    {
        // Disallow dimensions of size zero.

        rows = std::max(1U, rows);
        cols = std::max(1U, cols);

        // Construct each column vector and add to row vector.

        for (auto row = 0U; row < rows; ++row) {
            std::vector<int> new_row;
            for (auto col = 0U; col < cols; ++col) {
                new_row.push_back(0);
            }
            m_matrix.push_back(new_row);
        }
    }

    void set(unsigned col, unsigned row, int val) {
        // Set value, silently ignore invalid indexes.

        if (row < m_matrix.size() && col < m_matrix[0].size()) {
            m_matrix[row][col] = val;
        }
    }

    void print() {
        // Print out each column for each row.

        for (const auto &row: m_matrix) {
            for (const auto &val: row) {
                std::cout << std::setw(5) << val << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

private:
    // No need for destructor, vectors deallocate themselves.

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_matrix;
};

// Test code, though a bit light on test cases :-)

int main() {
    IntMatrix fourBySeven(4U, 7U);
    fourBySeven.set(2U, 4U, 42);
    fourBySeven.print();
}
```

The output of this, though bare bones, is what you would expect:

```
    0     0     0     0 
    0     0     0     0 
    0     0     0     0 
    0     0     0     0 
    0     0    42     0 
    0     0     0     0 
    0     0     0     0
```

Comment: This makes sense, however using this line of code now makes `edges = new vector<vector<int> >(rows*columns, vector<int>());` throw a bad_alloc for some reason.

Comment: You really want `rows*columns` vectors, not `rows*columns` number elements?